# Run WebView in a Backgroundtask

Tags: c#, angularjs, windows-10

I am creating a Windows 10 Universal app where the program runs in a WebView (a single-page AngularJS app) and the Windows app is communicating with it through a WebView. When the app is in the foreground, then there's no problem with it, but I have to call a JavaScript function from a BackgroundTask as well.

As I can see there is a possibility in Windows 10 to run a WebView in a Separate thread instead of the UI thread if the ExecutionMode property is setted to SeparateThread in the constructor. I tried to use this method in the BackgroundTask, but I still got the exception that I'm trying to create an object that is marshalled on a different thread.

Here's a code snippet:

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

    var tmp = WebView.DefaultExecutionMode;
    var webView = new WebView(WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateThread);
    var notificationService = new NotificationService(new BrowserBase { Browser = webView, IsOnUIThread = false });
        notificationService.Notification("ExampleCall");

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

I checked some other things. I've just put a button on the layout and binded this RelayCommand to it:

```
public RelayCommand Test
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(() => 
            {
                var tmp = new WebView(WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateThread);
                tmp.Navigate(_appBaseUri);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

As seen, I creating a WebView instance in a non-UI thread, but I still got exception even tough the WebView is created to run on a seperate thread.

Is there any way to do this? I am currently researching so I accept any help or idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding. You have to create the WebView on UI thread.

The SeparateThread execution mode means the webview will process and display content on non-UI thread to improve performance for specific scenarios. It's not to let you start a new thread and create the webview instance on that. The thread is automatically created and you will not be able to manage it.

If we have a busy UI and we have a lot of content to load, to avoid blocking on UI, we may start a new thread to load data and display the controls first. That makes the UI responsive. Actually, the SeparateThread execution mode does the similar thing.

So you need UI thread alive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I made some further research yesterday, I came to the same. It's very unfortunate because it would be much more easier for me if I would be able to create a webView in a non-UI thread, because I have to run JS ServiceCalls on a webpage. Now, I have to find a workaround for that. Do you have any suggestion about how can I run JavaScript coming from a certain webpage on a non-UI thread? If it helps I have the full sourceCode of the webpage as well.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?